# How to apply a different style of link?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have used this code to style the links in my menu

```
    a.special {
    color: #464646;
    outline: 0;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-size: 17px
}
```

Unfortunately I have other links in the middle of text which have also changed. After reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743355/how-can-i-make-different-html-links-different-colors  I think it might work but do not know how to apply "a.special" to a link. 
If I was to make the code

```
a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        outline: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px
    }
```

Then I need to apply it to the link.
How would I go about this?

Thanks for all your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would apply the `special` class using the `class` HTML attribute:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="special">I am special!</a>
```

The the selector `a.special` will match, and those rules will be used to style the link.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering... Would this work for headings as well? if I needed to make a heading 7 for example.

Comment: @Stonydallas It will work for any HTML element that supports styling, which is almost all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a heading 7, because there's only six different HTML headings (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 and h6; reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp), but you can make a heading 6 with this CSS code:

```
h6.special { color:#464646; outline:0;
    font-family:Raleway, sans-serif; font-size:17px; }
```

and this HTML code:

```
<h6 class="special">I am special!</h6>
```

PS: I removed the single quotes. You only need to use quotes if the font name consists of two words or more, for example 'Times New Roman'.